# how to multiple image upload using intent service with update UI from service

Tags: android

I am android developer .I have face issue ANR when multiple image send in background using intent service.I have call service on Resume() method.I have update UI when step by step image upload finish .My all code in service .But i don't understand why my UI hang.I have created ResultReceiver class for Update UI. Please tell me what is wrong i am doing.

```
public class UploadImageService extends IntentService {


public static final int STATUS_RUNNING = 0;
public static final int STATUS_FINISHED = 1;
public static final int STATUS_ERROR = 2;

private static final String TAG = "UploadImageService";
public static String SHOW_MSG = "showMsg";
public static String SET_IN_ADAPTER = "setData";
public static String UPLOAD_IMAGE = "uploadImage";
public static String RESULT = "result";

private String threadType, toUser, chatThreadId, gcmRegistrationId, openCloseChatWindowType, recipientName, threadTopicName, attachmentID, attachmentType, currentChunks, originalBase64Img, dateTime, classType, loginUserId;

// Declare Web services variable
private MultipartEntity multipartEntityBuilder;

Database database;

Bundle bundle;

ResultReceiver receiver;

public UploadImageService() {
    super(UploadImageService.class.getName());
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {


    //initialize database
    database = new Database(UploadImageService.this,  Database.DATABASE_NAME, null, Database.DATABASE_VERSION);

    Log.d(TAG, "Service Started!");

    receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver");

    try {



        bundle = new Bundle();

        /* Update UI: upload Service is Running */
        //receiver.send(STATUS_RUNNING, Bundle.EMPTY);

        try {
            new UploadThumbImageAsync().execute();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            bundle.putString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, e.toString());
            receiver.send(STATUS_ERROR, bundle);
        }

       /* new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while(true)
                {
                    try {
                          new UploadThumbImageAsync().execute();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        bundle.putString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, e.toString());
                        receiver.send(STATUS_ERROR, bundle);
                    }

                }

            }
        }).start();*/

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.e(TAG, "Service Stopping!");
    //this.stopSelf();
}
 private class UploadThumbImageAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    /*this method is use for initializing dialog(ProgressDialog,CustomDialog) and showing*/
    String toUser, comTypeId, threadType, chatThreadId, threadTopicName, chatAttachmentType, chatMessage, thumbBase64AttachmentPath /*original_image*/, loginUserName, recipientName, originalBase64Image, originalFilePath;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //showProgressDialog();
    }

    /*starts the loading of the data in background in doInBackground() method  */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            toUser = params[0];
            comTypeId = params[1];
            threadType = params[2];
            chatThreadId = params[3];
            threadTopicName = params[4];
            chatAttachmentType = params[5];
            chatMessage = params[6];
            thumbBase64AttachmentPath = params[7];
            loginUserName = params[8];
            recipientName = params[9];
            originalBase64Image = params[10];
            originalFilePath = params[11];
            String url;
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(threadType) && threadType.equals(RecentChatList.SIMPLE_TYPE)) {
                url = WS.URL.concat(WS.SAVE_CHAT);
            } else {
                url = WS.URL.concat(WS.GROUP_SAVE_CHAT);
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "url_" + chatMessage + " = " + url);
            String response = HttpClientExecuteMethod.executeMultipartPostMethod(url, multipartEntityBuilder);
            //Log.e(TAG, "save_chat_history_response_" + threadType + "_" + chatMessage + " =" + response);
            return response;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }

    /*This method is called after the background computation finishes.
        The result of background process in passed in this method as parameters
         and now you can dismiss progress dialog
        and get the result and display on onPostExecute() method
        */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        try {
            // Log.e(TAG, "chatAttachmentType = " + chatAttachmentType);
            updateCounter();
            if (result != null) {



                    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(result);
                    String success = null;
                    final int storeLimit = SharedPreference.getLimit(UploadImageService.this);

                    if (jo.has(WS.SUCCESS)) {
                        success = jo.getString(WS.SUCCESS);

                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(success) && success.equals("0")) {
                            return;
                        }

                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(success) && success.equals("100")) {

                            callWsSaveChat(chatAttachmentType, chatMessage, thumbBase64AttachmentPath, originalBase64Image, originalFilePath);
                            updateRecentChatAndThreadList();
                            return;
                        }

                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(success) && success.equals("99")) {

                            updateRecentChatAndThreadList();
                            return;
                        }


                    }


                    try {
                        ArrayList<Chat> saveChatArrayList = null;
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(success) && success.equals("1")) {

                            saveChatArrayList = new Chat().getChatHistory(UploadImageService.this, result, TAG, "");
                            // Log.e(TAG, "onPostExecute_saveChatArrayList.size = " + saveChatArrayList);

                            ArrayList<Chat> chatHistoryWithoutMsgId = database.getWithoutMsgIdChatHistory(chatThreadId, "#");
                            //Log.e(TAG, "onPostExecute_chatHistoryWithoutMsgId.size = " + chatHistoryWithoutMsgId.size());

                            if (saveChatArrayList != null && !saveChatArrayList.isEmpty() && saveChatArrayList.size() > 0) {

                                for (int i = 0; i < saveChatArrayList.size(); i++) {
                                    final Chat apiChat = saveChatArrayList.get(i);


                                    String apiMsg = apiChat.getMessage();
                                    String apiThumb = null;
                                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(apiChat.getAttachment_thumb())) {
                                        apiThumb = apiChat.getAttachment_thumb().concat("$");

                                    }

                                    if (chatHistoryWithoutMsgId != null && !chatHistoryWithoutMsgId.isEmpty() && chatHistoryWithoutMsgId.size() > 0) {
                                        for (int j = 0; j < chatHistoryWithoutMsgId.size(); j++) {

                                            Chat dbChat = chatHistoryWithoutMsgId.get(j);

                                            final String db_message = dbChat.getMessage();


                                            final String db_thumb = dbChat.getAttachment_thumb();

                                                    if (apiThumb.equals(db_thumb)) {
                                                        database.updateChatList(apiChat, result, "#", db_message, db_thumb, loginUserId, toUser, chatThreadId, threadType);


                                                     bundle.putString(RESULT, UPLOAD_IMAGE);
                                                      receiver.send(STATUS_FINISHED, bundle);

                                                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(chatAttachmentType) && chatAttachmentType.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.Image))) {
                                                            originalBase64Image = getBase64Image(originalFilePath);
                                                        }

                                                        int subLength = 1024 * 256;
                                                        //Log.e(TAG, "upload_subLength = " + subLength);
                                                        int index = 0;
                                                        int totalChunks = 0;
                                                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(originalBase64Image)) {
                                                            for (int k = 0; index < originalBase64Image.length(); k++) {
                                                                index = index + subLength;
                                                                totalChunks++;
                                                            }


                                            database.insertOriginalUploadImageList(apiChat.getAttachment_id(), totalChunks, 0, originalFilePath, chatThreadId, apiChat.getDt_sender_created(), chatAttachmentType);


                                                            // database.deleteAttachmentImageList(originalBase64Image);
                                                            database.deleteAttachmentImageList(originalFilePath);

                                                            UploadOriginalImageList(apiChat.getAttachment_id());

                                                        }
                                                  break;
                                                    } else {
                                                        // Log.e(TAG, "onPostExecute_not_equal_image");
                                                    }
                                                }

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }


                            }

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    // Util.showAlertDialog(mContext, mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.No_internet_connection_available));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "error = " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you uploading Images in `onPostExecute()` or Adding Images to DB?

Comment: yes first i have upload thumb image after  successfully thumb image then i have update data in DB and update UI then I have  insert upload  data in db and start upload original image same as thumb in using async class  in service

Comment: `onPostExecute` and `onPreExecute` both work on the main thread (UI thread), If you perform time consuming/large operations (like DB handling) on either of them, your UI will become unresponsive. Also make sure your code is not in an infinite loop.

Comment: yes I am sure my code is not in an infinite loop and  how can l manage UI upadte  on onPostExecute() method 
please help me
Thanks

Comment: Thats just it, only manage UI operations in `onPostExecute()` nothing else. Don't add Images to DB in `onPostExecute()` either put it in another `AsyncTask` or the same one. Infact it is highly recommended not to put Images in DB.

Comment: ok thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you abbas  once again your suggestion work .but I have one question I when I have send multiple image but not all Image send .one ya two image not send,service  break code??

Answer (score -1):

There are many methods to upload more images to the server.. one could be including two libraries: apache-mime4j-0.6.jar and httpmime-4.0.1.jar.. After that create your java main code:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FileUploadTest extends Activity {

private static final int SELECT_FILE1 = 1;
private static final int SELECT_FILE2 = 2;
String selectedPath1 = "NONE";
String selectedPath2 = "NONE";
TextView tv, res;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
Button b1,b2,b3;
HttpEntity resEntity;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    res = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.res);
    tv.setText(tv.getText() + selectedPath1 + "," + selectedPath2);
    b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button02);
    b3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.upload);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openGallery(SELECT_FILE1);
        }
    });
    b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openGallery(SELECT_FILE2);
        }
    });
    b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!(selectedPath1.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("NONE")) && !(selectedPath2.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("NONE"))){
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(FileUploadTest.this, "", "Uploading files to server.....", false);
                 Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            doFileUpload();
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                                public void run() {
                                    if(progressDialog.isShowing())
                                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                });
                thread.start();
            }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please select two files to upload.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

}

public void openGallery(int req_code){

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select file to upload "), req_code);
```

}

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE1)
        {
            selectedPath1 = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("selectedPath1 : " + selectedPath1);
        }
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE2)
        {
            selectedPath2 = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("selectedPath2 : " + selectedPath2);
        }
        tv.setText("Selected File paths : " + selectedPath1 + "," + selectedPath2);
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

private void doFileUpload(){

    File file1 = new File(selectedPath1);
    File file2 = new File(selectedPath2);



import java.io.File;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FileUploadTest extends Activity {

    private static final int SELECT_FILE1 = 1;
    private static final int SELECT_FILE2 = 2;
    String selectedPath1 = "NONE";
    String selectedPath2 = "NONE";
    TextView tv, res;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    Button b1,b2,b3;
    HttpEntity resEntity;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        res = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.res);
        tv.setText(tv.getText() + selectedPath1 + "," + selectedPath2);
        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button02);
        b3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.upload);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openGallery(SELECT_FILE1);
            }
        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openGallery(SELECT_FILE2);
            }
        });
        b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!(selectedPath1.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("NONE")) && !(selectedPath2.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("NONE"))){
                    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(FileUploadTest.this, "", "Uploading files to server.....", false);
                     Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable(){
                            public void run(){
                                doFileUpload();
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                                    public void run() {
                                        if(progressDialog.isShowing())
                                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                    });
                    thread.start();
                }else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please select two files to upload.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void openGallery(int req_code){

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select file to upload "), req_code);

 }


   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE1)
            {
                selectedPath1 = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("selectedPath1 : " + selectedPath1);
            }
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE2)
            {
                selectedPath2 = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("selectedPath2 : " + selectedPath2);
            }
            tv.setText("Selected File paths : " + selectedPath1 + "," + selectedPath2);
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    private void doFileUpload(){

        File file1 = new File(selectedPath1);
        File file2 = new File(selectedPath2);
        String urlString = "http://10.0.2.2/upload_test/upload_media_test.php";
        try
        {
             HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlString);
             FileBody bin1 = new FileBody(file1);
             FileBody bin2 = new FileBody(file2);
             MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
             reqEntity.addPart("uploadedfile1", bin1);
             reqEntity.addPart("uploadedfile2", bin2);
             reqEntity.addPart("user", new StringBody("User"));
             post.setEntity(reqEntity);
             HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
             resEntity = response.getEntity();
             final String response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
             if (resEntity != null) {
                 Log.i("RESPONSE",response_str);
                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        public void run() {
                             try {
                                res.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                                res.setText("n Response from server : n " + response_str);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Upload Complete. Check the server uploads directory.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                           }
                    });
             }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
             Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
      }
}
```

Now your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Multiple File Upload from CoderzHeaven"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Get First File">
</Button>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Get Second File">
</Button>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/upload"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start Upload">
</Button>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Selected File path : "
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/res"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text=""
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

of course, include the internet permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And voilà. Anyway i followed this example in my case: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/08/16/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-one-request-along-with-other-string-parameters-in-android/ try to see there.. There are 4 methods to upload multiple files. See which you like